# Proper way to (get from /insert into) table using Erlang Mysql Driver

Tags: mysql, erlang

I am trying to get `erlang-mysql-driver` working, I managed to set it up and make queries but there are two things I cannot do.(https://code.google.com/archive/p/erlang-mysql-driver/issues)

**(BTW, I am new to Erlang)**

So Here is my code to connect `MySQL`.

```
<erl>
out(Arg) -> 
            mysql:start_link(p1, "127.0.0.1", "root", "azzkikr", "MyDB"),
            {data, Result} = mysql:fetch(p1, "SELECT * FROM messages").
</erl>
```

## 1. I cannot get data from table.

`mysql.erl` doesn't contain any specific information on how to get table datas but this is the farthest I could go.

```
        {A,B} = mysql:get_result_rows(Result),
        B.
```

And the result was this:

```
ERROR erlang code threw an uncaught exception:
 File: /Users/{username}/Sites/Yaws/index.yaws:1
Class: error
Exception: {badmatch,[[4,0,<<"This is done baby!">>,19238],
                      [5,0,<<"Success">>,19238],
                      [6,0,<<"Hello">>,19238]]}
Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/"},{1,1}}
Stack: [{m181,out,1,
              [{file,"/Users/{username}/.yaws/yaws/default/m181.erl"},
               {line,18}]},
        {yaws_server,deliver_dyn_part,8,
                     [{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,2818}]},
        {yaws_server,aloop,4,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1232}]},
        {yaws_server,acceptor0,2,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,1068}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]
```

I understand that somehow I need to get second element and use **foreach** to get each data but strings are returned in different format like queried string is `Success` but returned string is `<<"Success">>`.

```
{badmatch,[[4,0,<<"This is done baby!">>,19238],
                      [5,0,<<"Success">>,19238],
                      [6,0,<<"Hello">>,19238]]}
```

First Question is: **How do I get datas from table?**

## 2. How to insert values into table using variables?

I can insert data into table using this method:

```
    Msg = "Hello World",
    mysql:prepare(add_message,<<"INSERT INTO messages (`message`)  VALUES (?)">>),
    mysql:execute(p1, add_message, [Msg]).
```

But there are two things I am having trouble,
1. I am inserting data without `<<` and `>>` operators, because When I do `Msg = << ++ "Hello World" >>,` erlang throws out an exception (I think I am doing something wrong), i don't know wether they are required but without them I am able to insert data into table except this error bothers me after execution:

```
yaws code at /Users/{username}/Yaws/index.yaws:1 crashed or ret bad val:{updated,
                                                                                 {mysql_result,
                                                                                  [],
                                                                                  [],
                                                                                  1,
                                                                                  []}} 
Req: {http_request,'GET',{abs_path,"/"},{1,1}}
```

returned atom is `updated` while I commanded to insert data.
Question 2 is:  **How do I insert data into table in a proper way?**

Comment: Why did you choose this particular mysql driver? It's from like 2007, when you probably still had to pay for Erlang! I would be surprised if it actually worked, both MySQL and Erlang went through a dozen or so version changes since then. Any reason for that?

Comment: If you have two questions you should split them to the two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error:

```erlang
{badmatch,[[4,0,<<"This is done baby!">>,19238],
                      [5,0,<<"Success">>,19238],
                      [6,0,<<"Hello">>,19238]]}
```

Tells you that returned values is:

```erlang
[[4,0,<<"This is done baby!">>,19238],
 [5,0,<<"Success">>,19238],
 [6,0,<<"Hello">>,19238]]
```

Which obviously can't match with either `{data, Data}` nor `{A, B}`. You can obtain your data as:

```erlang
<erl>
out(Arg) -> 
    mysql:start_link(p1, "127.0.0.1", "root", "azzkikr", "MyDB"),
    {ehtml,
     [{table, [{border, "1"}],
       [{tr, [],
         [{td, [],
           case Val of
               _ when is_binary(Val) -> yaws_api:htmlize(Val);
               _ when is_integer(val) -> integer_to_binary(Val)
           end}
          || Val <- Row
         ]}
        || Row <- mysql:fetch(p1, "SELECT * FROM messages")
       ]}
     ]
    }.
</erl>
```

Comment: Go to paradise, Thank You!